# Use of fontawesome icons in rallyApps

Tags: rally, appsdk2

I recently discovered that you can access some [fontawesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) fonts when using the app2sdk to very nice effect.  For example, here I'm using them to show trend arrows in a rallygrid:

[image]

This was so much easier than any alternative, for one because you can easily style these icons (in this example the color) just like a font.  It also give a wide array of useful icons ready to use.

But is it wise to use this feature?  This feature is working in rc2, but was not working in rc1, and I don't think it is documented anywhere.  Does anybody know if it is likely to keep working in future releases of the SDK?

Also, not all the icons are available- does this get updated periodically in Rally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have Rally icons, based on [Entypo](http://www.entypo.com/). This is a work in progress, so fonts may change in the future, but it is Rally's own set, and not all Entypo icons are available.

You may find out programmatically what icons of 'Rally' font-family  are available in a given release of AppSDK2  by running this custom app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>FontExplorer</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0rc2/sdk.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Rally.onReady(function () {
                Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    launch: function() {
        var fontStyles = _.find(document.styleSheets, function(styleSheet) {
            return styleSheet.href.match(/rui-fonts\.css$/);
        });
        var iconRules = _.filter(fontStyles.rules, function(rule) { 
            return rule.selectorText && rule.selectorText.match(/\.icon\-\w+\:\:before/) && rule.style[0] === 'content';  
        });

        this.add(_.map(iconRules, function(cssRule) {
            var iconName = cssRule.selectorText.substring(1).replace('::before', '');
            return {
                xtype: 'component',
                html: '<span style="font-family:courier" >' + iconName + '</span>',
                style: {
                    fontSize: '20px',
                    display: 'block'
                },
                cls: iconName,
                listeners: {
                    afterrender: function() {
                        if(this.getEl().getStyle('fontFamily') !== 'Rally') {
                            this.destroy();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };    
        }, this));
    }
});


            Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
                name:"FontExplorer",
           parentRepos:""
            });

        });
    </script>


    <style type="text/css">
        .app {
     /* Add app styles here */
}

    </style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way to determine what icons are available?

Comment: Please see the updated the answer that has a custom app code you may run to know what icons are available.

Comment: That is super awesome!  I do notice however that the up and down arrow I am using today do not appear.  Is there perhaps another group of fonts that aren't included in this app?

Comment: you may remove afterrender and stop filtering this.getEl().getStyle('fontFamily') !== 'Rally'                     and see other font families, including fontawsome. I cannot promise if we will continue including non Rally fonts in the future.